# Does this power path circuit work?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

I want when 5V input is available the battery to start charging and disconnect from output. Also when 5V is not present battery be connected to the output load. Will this idea will work? Can I use 10k for R-Pull?
[image: er]

Comment: why do you want to use `10k for R-Pull`?

Comment: @jsotola i read some where 10k is common for use as R-Pull . do you have any idea

Comment: I suggest that you simulate this circuit with something like LTspice to figure out whether the highlighted part of your circuit works or not

Comment: R-Pull looks like it is just connected across the power rails and is doing nothing but wasting power.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402199/powering-a-circuit-from-either-usb-or-lipo ?

Comment: @HandyHowie R-Pull might be required to pull the gate low and turn on the P-FET on power failure.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios exactly . thank you very much