# Power microcontroller directly from pins on a the LiPo battery charger board

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, lipo

I have a project that runs off a 1200mAh LiPo battery, which can be charged with a Mini-USB charging board to 2-pin JST as shown below.

I want to stow everything in an ABS plastic case and only expose the Mini USB port, to charge the battery. The charging port conveniently exposes the two pins, from which I could solder two wires and power my microcontroller. I would include a switch to make it possible to interrupt the power supply from the charging board to the microcontroller.

I don't have the schematics for the board I own, but this one from Sparkfun looks very similar (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10401, Schematics: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/Batteries/LiPo-Charger-Basic-MiniUSB-v10.pdf)

With the mini USB disconnected and the LiPo battery connected to the board a LED runs (for testing purposes) just fine using the two exposed pins on the board near the JST connector.

Now the question is: Is it okay to connect the microcontroller directly to the LiPo battery charging board like this? Would this work with the connected mini USB while charging the battery?

[image: LiPo battery charging board]

Comment: Most MCUs would like to run on a clean 3.3V. There are some MCUs with built-in regulators for the purpose of executing directly from a battery. So you'll either have to use one of those or design in an external voltage regulator. Otherwise the battery voltage is too unstable to be used for supplying logic circuits. As for what happens during charging, that's another story and I'm not sure how to design that in a safe way, if you wish the MCU to remain operational during charging.

Comment: No, you risk overcharging the battery and causing serious damage or even fire/explosion as the MCU load will confuse the charger. You need to implement a proper power path around the charger to power the MCU.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Lundin, the MCU should be fine with the battery attached directly, but I'll double check before actually building it. I just want to make sure the power supply is safe. I don't need the device to run during charging, just that it may happen that the power to the MCU isn't cut, before I connect the charger.

Comment: Thank you @Finbarr! That makes sense. Could you elaborate the "proper power path"? I'd love to construct this in a way, that I don't have to disassemble the case to charge the battery.

Comment: @lisa-thehexbit Any MCU out there absolutely does require a _stable_ voltage, no matter if it is 3 to 5V tolerant or not. And any half-decent MCU has a low-voltage detect circuit built in. Thats why these MCUs with built-in step-down converters were made, to be driven directly from a single Li/Ion cells.

Comment: A question like this is asked almost daily so have a search on lithium charging power path or similar. Simplest arrangement is two diodes like shown in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402199/powering-a-circuit-from-either-usb-or-lipo/). You might not need a regulator depending on your load.

Comment: @Lundin from what I've read, the Raspberry Pi Pico can be run directly from LiPo batteries.

Comment: @lisa-thehexbit Yep it appears to exactly such an MCU as I mentioned. https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/rp2040/ As you can see in the blocks there, it has a voltage regulator on-chip. This is a special feature and not the norm for MCUs.

Comment: @Finbarr I assume that if attempting something like that, it might be a good idea to use a charger IC with thermistor input for extra safety.